# Managesieve roundcube - retrieve original email subject and body with {tags}

Tags: email, dovecot, roundcube

I am using roundcube with managesieve plugin, and have setup a Vacation message.
I would like to know if there is an option to retrieve the `subject` of the original email send by a user to be used inside my "Vacation message".

For instance I would like to retrieve both the `subject` and the `body` of the email that was send, in return the user that send the email should receive an email like this:

```
Dear customer,

We will reply to your question "{email_subject}" shortly. Below a copy of your message:

{email_body}
```

As you can see the {email_subject} and {email_body} should then be replaced automatically with the original email data.

I couldn't find any information about this, so I am suspecting this isn't possible with managesieve, but if so please let me know where to find this information, and if not, how to program it myself possibly?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I generally recommend against using anything from the incoming message besides the sender address. A spammer could otherwise use your vacation system to spread his message. A normal sender will generally know what he sent, especially as a vacation message usually arrives a couple of moments after sending the original email; so no need to remind the sender.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, this possibility has been left out intentionally to avoid unwanted Spam. However I did manage to retrieve the "Subject" from the original message. To bad it's not possible :( Do you have some source/documentation link to read up on this? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't know if it's been left out, it's just that I would never use it. Spammers can send their spam to someone that's on vacation, with the intended recipient as the fake sender.